# Can I say 'I sleeped all night' instead of slept?

Tags: past-tense

Slept is out dated but appears to be needed in this case?

Comment: "Slept" is not outdated.

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think it's outdated? It's an old form, but it's still the right word. Trying to force a modern verb ending on one that won't take it is just not going to work.

Sleep/slept, weep/wept, keep/kept all follow a similar pattern.

The only ones that spring to mind which have changed over the years are 'leap' and 'treat'.
Northern Br Eng still uses 'treat' [pronounced tret] as the past tense, even though Southern Br Eng would use 'treated' [tree-ted].
Leap also has a 'split personality'. IMO, the 'correct' past tense is leapt [pronounced but never spelled lept], though the modern form leaped [leept] is common. My own assumption is that it's some kind of back-formation even spelled that way & still ought to be pronounced 'lept'.
I also think the rise in the use of the actual spelling as 'lept' is simply illiteracy... ask me about it again in 50 years ;)

*Late find:* [ELU - “Lept” vs. “leapt” vs. “leaped”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/76167/99969)

Comment: Compare also _spelt_ and _learnt_. These are still common in British English, but I think the alternatives _spelled_ and _learned_ are the only ones used in American English.

Comment: Yes - I'm sure we could eventually find a long list of them. There are several I hadn't thought of in the linked question on ELU. I think ultimately it becomes "some you can do it to, some you can't"; even if that eventually becomes 'can't yet'

Comment: Brits often pronounce 'leapt' as if it were 'lept'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - as I already said in my answer...

Comment: The answer to the question is no, it is not needed in "this case": I slept all night. What do you mean force a modern verb ending on to sleep? Sleep is irregular, unlike walk, talk and others that take ed. ed is not modern.